# Elasticsearch default no results on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch

On my index page I have `streams` displayed and they can be searched using elasticsearch.

```
  def index

    @streams = Stream.search(params)

  end
```

When the page loads, all the results are displayed and the user can do a search and the results of the search will be displayed.

How can I have it so that when the page loads, by default, no results are displayed? Only when the user does a search do results get returned.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would set which `params` is related to your user search. You could store it in something like `params[:search]`. Then all you have to do is a check on the content of `params[:search]`:

```
def index
  @streams = params[:search] ? Stream.search(params[:search]) : Stream.none
end
```

`Stream.none` is a rails 4 method that will return an empty relation

Comment: this seems to always return no results

Comment: "How can I have it so that when the page loads, by default, no results are displayed" Isn't returning no results what you want? If you mean that even with `params[:search]` being set you get no results, I will need additionnal code to help you, like the content of `Stream.search` method